# How to replace a substring in a line that contains another substring

Tags: regex

I have this lines.

I want for each line that contains "Id" of any case to replace "string" with int.

Not sure how to do grouping for this.

This is my list

I've tried something like this `^(.*(string).*(Id).*)$` and replace with `\1` or `\2`

```
public string ID {get; set}
public string IdSite {get; set}
public string IdParent {get; set}
public string IdPageType {get; set}
public string PageType {get; set}
public string IdTemplate {get; set}
public string TemplateName {get; set}
public string IdTemplateParent {get; set}
```

Comment: Try `string(?=.*?id)` and enable case-insensitive match.

Comment: @revo, thanks this worked, if you post the answer i ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match entire line or capture anything. Instead try:

```
string(?=.*?id)
```

The [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) asserts that `id` comes somewhere after `string`. Also to match `id` in any form you should enable case-insensitive match or use `[iI][dD]` in favor of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?i)^(\s*\w+\s+)string(\s+Id)
```

Or, if the `ID` may be inside a word

```
(?i)^(\s*\w+\s+)string(\s+\w*Id)
                          ^^^
```

Replace with `$1int$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQckvO/1). See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5Cs*%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B)string(%5Cs%2B%5Cw*Id)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive inline option
- `^` - start of a line (or string, if not used in a text editor, use `(?im)` at the start instead of `(?i)`)
- `(\s*\w+\s+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): 0+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars, 1+ whitespaces
- `string` - a `string` word
- `(\s+Id)` - Group 2 (`$2`): 1+ whitespaces and `ID` string  (if you use `\w*` in this group pattern, it will match 0+ word chars).